# How Can i make an image to appear in facebook link which is in the body of html website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on an FB App and i want the result image which is on my website to appear with the link that I post on Facebook so that people can see my result image.

How can I do that? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the property `og:image` of Facebook API this way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        …
        <meta property="og:image" content="path_of_image" />
    </head>
    <body>
        …
    </body>
</html>
```

You can find more informations about **Open Graph Protocol** [here](http://ogp.me/) and about **Facebook Content Sharing** [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)

Comment: My Image is being generated dynamically in div tag via Php,is there anyway i can accomplish that thing

Comment: Simply add the PHP code thata generate image inside the path, something like this: <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo … ?>" />